# How to load multiple html files from directory to a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load all the html files into a single div using jquery.

```
$("#search_content").load('components/1.html','components/2.html','components/3.html');
```

But it loads  the first file only. I need to load all the files from the components directory into search content div. And also i'm searching the string from this div. all content's are in 'p' tag. i need to find its occurance and its parent file. for example, if i search the string 'google'.  i need to get it's 'p' tag accurance like 3 and its parent file 'components/2.html'.

```
var occurance = $('p').index(this);
```

But it returns only the total occurance. I need to get the filename and the occurance from that file only

Please help me. I struck in this for 2 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to load all the files from a directory

Comment: the answer in duplicate question is not good.